# Run grunt task with target/argument in VSCode

Tags: gruntjs, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode version 1.18.1, and this in my `Gruntfile.js`

```
grunt.registerTask('release', 'Release process', function(target) {
    ...
}
```

The `target` is there so that I can run `grunt release:one` or `grunt release:two`. However, I can't figure out how to make VSCode run the task with the `one|two` target.

This is `tasks.json` file VSCode created with Grunt task auto detected.

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "grunt",
        "task": "release",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "label": "Release Process",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

If I put `release:one` to the `task` attribute of the `tasks.json` file, VSCode will complain with something like

```
Error: The grunt task detection didn't contribute a task for the following configuration:
```

Anyone has done something similar to this? Can you please guide me on how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: I had similar issue with gulp. I have reinstalled vscode.

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this issue myself was by creating a Task of type `shell` instead, and putting in the full command. For example, you can do following:

`{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Release one",
            "command": "grunt release:one",
            "problemMatcher": [],
        }, {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Release two",
            "command": "grunt release:two",
            "problemMatcher": [],
        }
    ]
}`